# My object is not updated even if I use the pointer to a type to update it

Tags: pointers, go, methods, slice

I store some `Individual` objects in a slice. Before appending it to the slice I print the name of the `Individual` object.

After I have stored it in the slice, I then retrieve it as a pointer and want to change the name to `"Peter"`, but the change does not work since it still prints `"Steve"`. Why?

```
type Individual interface {
    GetName() *string
    SetName(name string)
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

// Implement functions of the Individual interface
func (p Person) GetName() *string  {
    return &p.name
}

func (p Person) SetName(newName string)  {
    name := p.GetName();
    *name = newName
}


var individuals []Individual

func main() {
    person := Person{name: "Steve"}
    fmt.Println(person)

    individuals = append(individuals, person) // append Person to slice
    p1 := individuals[0]     // Retrieve the only Person from slice
    p1.SetName("Peter")      // Change name
    fmt.Println(p1)          // Should print "Peter", but prints "Steve"
    fmt.Println(person)      // Should print "Peter", but prints "Steve"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whenever a method wants to modify the receiver, **it must be a pointer to the value**; the method must have a pointer receiver.

If a method has a non-pointer receiver, a copy will be made and passed when that method is called. From that point, no matter what you do with the receiver, you can only modify the copy, and not the original.

So in your example:

```
func (p Person) SetName(newName string)  {
    name := p.GetName();
    *name = newName
}
```

When `SetName()` is called, a copy is made of the `Person`. Inside `SetName()` you obtain the address of the `name` field of the **copy**, which you modify. *(Actually, a **copy of the copy**, more on this later...)*

Solution: use a pointer receiver:

```
func (p *Person) SetName(newName string)  {
    name := p.GetName();
    *name = newName
}
```

From this point on, only `*Person` implements `Individual`, so use a pointer when appending:

```
individuals = append(individuals, &person)
```

It's tricky, because after this it sill won't work. Why is that?

It is because the `Person.GetName()` still has a non-pointer receiver:

```
func (p Person) GetName() *string {
    return &p.name
}
```

So when `GetName()` is called from `SetName()`, a copy will be made again, and `GetName()` will return the address of the `name` field of the **copy**, and `SetName()` will only modify the copy created for calling `GetName()`.

So to make all work, you also have to use pointer receiver for `GetName()`:

```
func (p *Person) GetName() *string {
    return &p.name
}
```

And now it's working, output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wOA74mA1Q5)):

```
{Steve}
&{Peter}
{Peter}
```

But know that the easiest and recommended way is simply:

```
func (p *Person) SetName(newName string) {
    p.name = newName
}
```

That's all it takes.

Comment: I assume it would be more idiomatic for `GetName` to return the `string` by-value?

Comment: Thank you for a good response! If I call `p1 := individuals[0]` several times and then print the address with `fmt.Println(&p1)` after each call I get different addresses each time. `p2 := individuals[0]` and then `fmt.Println(&p2)` will print another address. Why?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes, obviously. I just wanted to guide through from the code what the asker presented, because I think it is edifying / illuminating (that _copy of copy_ part is not self-evident).

Comment: @Rox `p1 := individuals[0]` is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), which creates a local variable, and `&p1` is the address of the _local variable_ (and not the pointer value should it contain a pointer), which will (might) be different each time.

Answer (score 4):

Two things to fix this:

- You need the methods attach via a "pointer" method, otherwise the name is only changed inside the method.
- You need to use pointers for the actual `Person` variables, since they need to implement an interface

```golang
type Individual interface {
    GetName() *string
    SetName(name string)
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

// Implement functions of the Individual interface
func (p Person) GetName() *string  {
    return &p.name
}

func (p *Person) SetName(newName string)  {
    p.name = newName
}


var individuals []Individual

func main() {
    person := &Person{name: "Steve"}
    fmt.Println(person)

    individuals = append(individuals, person) // append Person to slice
    p1 := individuals[0]     // Retrieve the only Person from slice
    p1.SetName("Peter")      // Change name
    fmt.Println(p1)          // Prints "Steve"
    fmt.Println(person)      // Prints "Steve"
}
```

Example on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L7E74qLxWw).

Comment: As it stands I think `GetName` is a bit misleading. It is returning a pointer to `string` in a copy of a `Person`. I assume the method should either have a pointer receiver or return by-value, no?

Answer (score 0):

See https://play.golang.org/p/eg8oYDV6Xx p1 and p2 are already addresses, you don't need to their address (address of address), just print p1 and p2 - they'll be the same as you can see.